# IntelliJ IDE hotkey or shortcut to swap x with y when there is a code like x=y

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, datagrip, appcode

Is there a shortcut to swap `x` and `y` during assignment `x = y`. For example:

```
some_object.some_property = another_object.another_property
```

becomes

```
another_object.another_property = some_object.some_property
```

Comment: There is no built-in action for this. Two plugins that can help here: 1) Shifter plugin -- select lines and invoke Shift+Up action -- it will flip the stuff around `=`. 2) String manipulation plugin -- select lines and invoke Swap Characters/Selections/Lines/Tokens. requires extra step to specify the delimiter symbol (`=` in your  case). In both cases -- they will not handle end of statement/element symbols (e.g. `;` or `,`) -- they will treat it as a part of right side statement. There is also "Permute list element/xml attribute" plugin that may do it better but I haven't never used it myself

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: i use python....but does it matter?